# Minecraft block detection for a specific block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to use commands or redstone devices (or a combination) to detect for a *specific* block placed in a *specific* coordinate and output a redstone current if so?

For instance, if I place a stone block in the coordinates (1,2,3), a command block will execute.

I'm sure /testforblock could be useful, but I just can't figure out how. All that does is tests if a block is there; it doesn't do anything if that resolves to true.

Assume version 1.12, if that makes things easier.

*Bonus points:* Same thing, but detecting if a specific *entity* is in the supplied coordinates. Again, /testfor seems useful, but I'm unsure how.

Comment: What's with the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place a comparator in front of a command block with

```
testforblock x y z
```

Then it should yield a redstone signal. You may want to place a repeater in front of the comparator.

A visual guide:

[image]